# MQ on Wildfly - same message received multiple times

Tags: jms, wildfly, ibm-mq

I try to subscribe to a messagequeue by using MQ and wildfly and i have a strange behavior with my MQ Client source. I'am receiving the same message multiple times, on my server is no exception thrown. The output in my logfile looks like this (this is just a testcode, i reduced the source to a simple log-output to exclude the complexity):

```
2018-11-28 15:06:14,927 INFO   [com.mystuff.interfaces.messages.MyMessageListener] Message consumed: ID:c3e2d840d8f0f1e34040404040404040d5204b6ac8457cd1(js=,t=default-threads - 49)
2018-11-28 15:06:14,930 INFO   [com.mystuff.interfaces.messages.MyMessageListener] Message consumed: ID:c3e2d840d8f0f1e34040404040404040d5204b6ac8457cd1(js=,t=default-threads - 2)
2018-11-28 15:06:14,930 INFO   [com.mystuff.interfaces.messages.MyMessageListener] Message consumed: ID:c3e2d840d8f0f1e34040404040404040d5204b6ac8457cd1(js=,t=default-threads - 1)
2018-11-28 15:06:15,014 INFO   [com.mystuff.interfaces.messages.MyMessageListener] Message consumed: ID:c3e2d840d8f0f1e34040404040404040d5204b6ac8457cd1(js=,t=default-threads - 21)
2018-11-28 15:06:15,027 INFO   [com.mystuff.interfaces.messages.MyMessageListener] Message consumed: ID:c3e2d840d8f0f1e34040404040404040d5204b6ac8457cd1(js=,t=default-threads - 32)
2018-11-28 15:06:15,044 INFO   [com.mystuff.interfaces.messages.MyMessageListener] Message consumed: ID:c3e2d840d8f0f1e34040404040404040d5204b6ac8457cd1(js=,t=default-threads - 45)
2018-11-28 15:06:15,050 INFO   [com.mystuff.interfaces.messages.MyMessageListener] Message consumed: ID:c3e2d840d8f0f1e34040404040404040d5204b6ac8457cd1(js=,t=default-threads - 40)
2018-11-28 15:06:15,130 INFO   [com.mystuff.interfaces.messages.MyMessageListener] Message consumed: ID:c3e2d840d8f0f1e34040404040404040d5204b6ac8457cd1(js=,t=default-threads - 28)
2018-11-28 15:06:15,133 INFO   [com.mystuff.interfaces.messages.MyMessageListener] Message consumed: ID:c3e2d840d8f0f1e34040404040404040d5204b6ac8457cd1(js=,t=default-threads - 34)
2018-11-28 15:06:15,145 INFO   [com.mystuff.interfaces.messages.MyMessageListener] Message consumed: ID:c3e2d840d8f0f1e34040404040404040d5204b6ac8457cd1(js=,t=default-threads - 14)
2018-11-28 15:06:15,159 INFO   [com.mystuff.interfaces.messages.MyMessageListener] Message consumed: ID:c3e2d840d8f0f1e34040404040404040d5204b6ac8457cd1(js=,t=default-threads - 32)
2018-11-28 15:06:15,165 INFO   [com.mystuff.interfaces.messages.MyMessageListener] Message consumed: ID:c3e2d840d8f0f1e34040404040404040d5204b6ac8457cd1(js=,t=default-threads - 8)
```

The interesting thing is that

- Some messages are received only 1 time, some thousands of times
- The messages are commited after some time, the queue gets empty
- The queue is of a third party provider, so it's a kind of black box for me (no server sided logs and so on, i'am only on the client side)

May be there is a transaction problem and the commit happens to late and till the commit happens the system reads the message multiple times?! I have no idea...

Here is an example of a message (without the content, only the header):

```
JMSMessage class: jms_text
  JMSType:          null
  JMSDeliveryMode:  2
  JMSDeliveryDelay: 0
  JMSDeliveryTime:  0
  JMSExpiration:    0
  JMSPriority:      5
  JMSMessageID:     ID:c3e2d840d8f0f1e34040404040404040d5204b6ac8457cd1
  JMSTimestamp:     1540366098490
  JMSCorrelationID: ID:c3e2d840d8f0f1e34040404040404040d5204b6ac8457cd1
  JMSDestination:   null
  JMSReplyTo:       queue://Q01T/R121.G6.?targetClient=1
  JMSRedelivered:   false
    JMSXAppID: RPRI196Y                    
    JMSXDeliveryCount: 1
    JMSXUserID: RPRI196     
    JMS_IBM_Character_Set: IBM273
    JMS_IBM_Encoding: 785
    JMS_IBM_Format: MQSTR   
    JMS_IBM_MsgType: 8
    JMS_IBM_PutApplType: 2
    JMS_IBM_PutDate: 20181024
    JMS_IBM_PutTime: 07281849
```

Here is the jboss-ejb3.xml config:

```
<message-driven>
            <ejb-name>Testmdb.xxxxx</ejb-name>
            <ejb-class>com.mystuff.messages.TestMessageListener</ejb-class>
            <transaction-type>Container</transaction-type>
            <activation-config>
                <activation-config-property>
                    <activation-config-property-name>messagingType</activation-config-property-name>
                    <activation-config-property-value>javax.jms.MessageListener</activation-config-property-value>
                </activation-config-property>
                <activation-config-property>
                    <activation-config-property-name>destinationType</activation-config-property-name>
                    <activation-config-property-value>${xxxxx.mq.defaultdestinationType}</activation-config-property-value>
                </activation-config-property>
                <activation-config-property>
                    <activation-config-property-name>destination</activation-config-property-name>
                    <activation-config-property-value>java:/xxxx</activation-config-property-value>
                </activation-config-property>
                <activation-config-property>
                    <activation-config-property-name>useJNDI</activation-config-property-name>
                    <activation-config-property-value>true</activation-config-property-value>
                </activation-config-property>
                <activation-config-property>
                    <activation-config-property-name>channel</activation-config-property-name>
                    <activation-config-property-value>${xxxxx.mq.channel.xxxxx}</activation-config-property-value>
                </activation-config-property>
                <activation-config-property>
                    <activation-config-property-name>hostName</activation-config-property-name>
                    <activation-config-property-value>${xxxxx.mq.hostName}</activation-config-property-value>
                </activation-config-property>
                <activation-config-property>
                    <activation-config-property-name>queueManager</activation-config-property-name>
                    <activation-config-property-value>${xxxxx.mq.queueManager}</activation-config-property-value>
                </activation-config-property>
                <activation-config-property>
                    <activation-config-property-name>port</activation-config-property-name>
                    <activation-config-property-value>${xxxxx.mq.port}</activation-config-property-value>
                </activation-config-property>
                <activation-config-property>
                    <activation-config-property-name>transportType</activation-config-property-name>
                    <activation-config-property-value>CLIENT</activation-config-property-value>
                </activation-config-property>
                <activation-config-property>
                    <activation-config-property-name>acknowledgeMode</activation-config-property-name>
                    <activation-config-property-value>AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE</activation-config-property-value>
                </activation-config-property>
            </activation-config>
        </message-driven>

<mdb:resource-adapter-binding>
    <ejb-name>Testmdb.xxxxx</ejb-name>
    <mdb:resource-adapter-name>wmq.jmsra</mdb:resource-adapter-name>
</mdb:resource-adapter-binding>
```

Here is the .cli config:

```
/subsystem=resource-adapters/resource-adapter=wmq.jmsra:add(archive=wmq.jmsra.rar, transaction-support=XATransaction)

/subsystem=resource-adapters/resource-adapter=wmq.jmsra/admin-objects=xxxx:add(class-name="com.ibm.mq.connector.outbound.MQQueueProxy", jndi-name="java:/xxxx")
/subsystem=resource-adapters/resource-adapter=wmq.jmsra/admin-objects=xxxx/config-properties=baseQueueName/:add(value=xxxx)
/subsystem=resource-adapters/resource-adapter=wmq.jmsra/admin-objects=xxxx/config-properties=targetClient/:add(value=MQ)
```

Software-Versions:

- 8.0.0.10
- Wildfly 11

Comment: When I see the Message Id and Correlation Id the same for a message, my radar goes off.  Is the sending application setting the Message Id?  Because if it is then that is the source of the problem.  The Message Id must be unique for each message.  Also, are you performing a destructive get or browse get?

Comment: I don't know if the MessageID is set by the sending application, but i will try to find out. I hope i do a destructive get (as i understand this deletes the message after reading it), but i'am not sure. I didn't do any special MQGet configuration (so far as i know). How can i verify that i do a destructive get?

Comment: @Roger: This was the right answer, the did something strange with the message id. Please answer the question so that i can mark it as the right answer.